# Find solutions to magic puzzle with sums

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, puzzle, gaussian-elimination

I need help to solve the folowing puzzle using linear algebra (matrix and Gauss-Jordan Method):

(for example the second horinzontal line: `w + w + w + z = 45` or the second vertical line `y + w + x + w = 46`)

```
x   y   z   w   ?
w   w   w   z   45
y   x   y   x   48
z   w   y   z   53
?   46  59  41
```

The problem is to find the value of **`?`** (and also the value of **x,y,z** and **w**), I tried to solve this, creating the matrix:

```
1   1   1   1   a
0   0   1   3   45
2   2   0   0   48
0   1   2   1   53
```

this matrix corresponds to the following systems of linear equations:

```
x + y + z + w = a
0x + 0y + z + 3w = 45
2x + 2y + 0z + 0w = 48
0x + y + 2z + w = 53
```

I could not find the values **x,y,z** and **w** and the value of **a**, for solve the vertical and horizontal sums . Appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: As I see it, you are missing two things. The first is the vertical equations, that are the equivalent of the traspose of your matriz, and the vector $(b,46,59,41)$. The second one, is the fact that you have 6 variables ($a,y,z,w,a,b$) and 8 equations given by the horizontal and vertical sums: this might give you no answers at all, or infinite answers if the equations are linearly dependent.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at 3rd row first, y+x+y+x=48, we get y+x=24. Then we look at 2nd column, y+w+x+w=46, so 2w = 46-24 = 22, w = 11. Because w+w+w+z = 45, z = 45-33 = 12. Therefore, x+y+z+w = 24+11+12 = 47.